# How to setup jarvis voice from other source?

Tags: python

```
hereengine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
```

Comment: as I know pyttsx3 doesn't use sources but it generates audio using code - so it can work `offline`. Different engines may use different methods to generate audio from parameters.

Comment: You would have to search details for `sapi5` - maybe there are files with different parameters, and maybe there are descriptions in which folder put these files.